# Why isn't my assembly program setting r1 to the correct value?

Tags: assembly, simulator, cpu-registers, machine-code, lc3

I am writing an assembly program on the LC3 machine.

My assembly program is an  LC3 program that multiplies R2 and R3 and stores the result in R1.

Here is my source code(with comments)

```
;Sets pc to this address at start of program 
.ORIG x3000
;R1 will store the result lets clear it(ANd with 0)
AND R1,R1,x0
;R2 will be multiplied by R3, let's clear both of them 
AND R2,R2,x0
AND R3,R3,x0
;Test case 4 * 3 = 12;
ADD R2,R2,4
ADD R3,R3,3
;Add to increment zone 
LOOP Add R1,R1,R2;
;Decrement the counter, in this case the 3 or R3
ADD R3,R3,x-1
BrP LOOP
HALT
.END
```

My test case is multiplying 4 * 3. The result should be 12 and that should be stored in R1. However when I run this program in my LC3 simulator, this is what i get for the output[image]

R3 holds the correct value at the end but R1 holds -1.... Does anyone see an issue with my code? I made sure to clear R1 at the beginning and to keep adding R3 to R1 and storing the result to R1 while the counter, R3, or 3 in this case is greater than zero.

Comment: I just run your program and that's not what I'm getting. Where did you put your breakpoint? You should put it at HALT instruction. Otherwise your values might be overwritten by the HALT trap.

Comment: Also note you're not using R2 anywhere in your loop.

Comment: Isn't breakpoint just for debugging? Why put a breakpoint at the HALT instruction? Doesn't HALT already stop the program?

Comment: I fixed my R2 to make sure that I store the result of R1 + R2 gets stored in R1. Does that look good now?

Comment: HALT doesn't stop the CPU in the simulator I have, it's in fact a pseudo instruction (TRAP HALT). This is a learning machine, it doesn't perform any actual useful results, so to check if your program is working fine you need to either stop it before it finishes or print the results somewhere.

Comment: Yeah thanks for clarifying that. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT says that HALT does stop the CPU. Confusing. But do you know what the issue with my program is? I placed the halt at TRP and it still produced that output, R1 at -1?

Comment: That HLT instruction is for x86, not for LC3. Each architecture is different. Again, if you execute HALT, your registers will be messed up by the code in the software interruption. You can check what HALT does by going step by step through your program, and you will see it jumps to another code.

Comment: Is this updated program producing the right output in your simulation?

Comment: That's up to you to check, this way you learn to use the simulator.

Comment: Thanks for making me eat my vegetables :)

Comment: What do you mean by psuedo instruction?  From here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRAP_%28processor_instruction%29 , I read that  "Trap Halt is a routine used for ending programs". How would this mess up the registers? It should just end the program. That wiki article was about the LC3 assembly langauge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HALT` is just a "pseudo-instruction" for a TRAP instruction used to halt the machine.

You could write:

```
TRAP x25  ;HALT the machine
```

But in this way you need to remember the position in the TRAP vector, in this case `x25`. So is better to just use `HALT` instead.

Others common TRAPs also have pseduo-instructions: `IN`, `OUT`, etc.

I asume you want to store your results somewhere. You could do something like:

```
;Sets pc to this address at start of program 
.ORIG x3000
;R1 will store the result lets clear it(ANd with 0)
AND R1,R1,x0
;R2 will be multiplied by R3, let's clear both of them 
AND R2,R2,x0
AND R3,R3,x0
;Test case 4 * 3 = 12;
ADD R2,R2,4
ADD R3,R3,3
;Add to increment zone 
LOOP Add R1,R1,R2;
;Decrement the counter, in this case the 3 or R3
ADD R3,R3,x-1
BrP LOOP
ST R1, Result         ;STORE R1 at Result
HALT
Result .FILL x0000    ;this will be x000C=12h after execution
.END
```

**---------------------EDIT--------------------------**

About you last question (in comments):

> If HALT stops my program, how will Reslt .FILL x0000 directive run
>   then?

This is more a question about how assemblers works.

The answer is because: **Assembly Time** != **Execution Time**

Directives are considered at Assembly Time.

In fact, Assembly Time is composed in two passes:

1. Resolve symbols creating a symbol table
2. Convert instructions to "truly executable/machine code" using the symbol table.

This is a very common way to implement assemblers, and the LC3 assembler is not the exception.

Comment: Shouldn't this store the result? LOOP Add R1,R1,R2;
Add R1 and R2 and store the result of adding data of those registers in R1?

Comment: @committedandroider At the end of your LOOP, R1 have the result. But... when you HALT the machine, you are calling a "special routine" where registers are used again so their content is changed.

Comment: What should i call instead to not have the contents changed? just .END and not HALT?

Comment: Why call Result .FILL x0000 ? Didn't you already call ST R1, Result  to store the register in R1?

Comment: @committedandroider After HALT, there aren't instructions. Your program stops at HALT, that's why youu need HALT. `Result .FILL x0000` is just a directive for the assembler to RESERVE some space that will be used later at execution time, you can think of `Result` as a variable if you like. So... `ST R1, Result` is storing the result in the variable `Result`.

Comment: I am confused with the logic you stated. If HALT stops my program, how will Reslt .FILL x0000 directive run then?

Comment: @committedandroider Edited my answer to address your last question.

Comment: Thank you!! Can you check up on this one as well? http://superuser.com/questions/904324/which-of-the-following-instructions-can-reference-a-memory-location-that-is-100    I need your expertise in assembly language :)